# cURL get the API data to show in php table

Tags: php, api, curl, get

i have this api with a lot of campaigns, i need to get to show specific campaigns from the last month like the name of the campaign, and the status, but i cannot figure it o ut how to do so..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Campaign Exclude App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Campaigns</h1><br>
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="submit">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Campaign Name</th>
      <th scope="col">CPA Goal</th>
      <th scope="col">Click Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<?php
$url='https://www.popads.net/api/campaign_list?key=9a790b65025e0aa449e60384a87b56e97c3ebf39';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$resultArray = json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultArray);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWVo.png)

Comment: campaign_list will list all campaigns. You can filter the results using PHP functions. If you have any other reference material. you can share within question

Comment: and how can i filter the results?

Comment: see the [docs](https://doc.voluum.com/en/voluum_api_docs.html), something like: `https://www.popads.net/api/campaign_list?key=9a790b65025e0aa449e60384a87b56e97c3ebf39?from=2020-07-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-08-01T00:00:00Z&tz=Etc/GMT`

Comment: this is not working...

Comment: what do you want to filter? what are your requirements? Their rest API is at an early stage. You need to perform operations at your end

Comment: i want to filter campaigns that were created in the last month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list records within the last 30 days, you can filter the curl response as below

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.popads.net/api/campaign_list?key=9a790b65025e0aa449e60384a87b56e97c3ebf39';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$resultArray = json_decode($result, true);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Campaign Exclude App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Campaigns</h1><br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <input type="submit">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Campaign Name</th>
                <th scope="col">CPA Goal</th>
                <th scope="col">Click Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
            $lastmonth = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-1 months', strtotime($today)));
            foreach ($resultArray['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
                if ($campaign['created'] > $lastmonth) {

            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><?php echo $campaign['id']; ?> </td>
                        <td scope="col"><?php echo $campaign['name']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="col"><?php echo $campaign['xxxxxxx']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="col"><?php echo $campaign['xxxxxxx']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php }
            } ?>
        </thead>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i set the date for july?